# How to remove useless indents at the beginning of each line in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

Now I have these indents after each line number in the file created in PyCharm:[image]

How to remove these indents after lines' numbers?

Answer (score 5):

Select the code (lines), press `Shift` + `Tab`

Comment: The text does not go closer to the numbers.

Comment: In that case, there is no "useless indent".  
In my  (community)version, there is a light-grey colored column, holding the line numbers and ohter indicators - I don't know of any way to get rid of that column.

Comment: Most helpful reply if I ever saw one. These obvious but hard to put in words functions are the worst to research

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and the way how I solved it was, click on 'View' at the top of the page and then click 'Appearance' and 'Exit Distraction Free Mode', like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ze393.png)
It should remove your 'tabs' before each line and makes your IDE simple.